# Как пишется наречие "(в)черную"?

Tags: орфография, наречия

*Пивовары, особенно в крупных городах, работают официально и (в)черную ничего не продают.* Цитата из текста. Как пишется наречие "(в)черную"?

Answer (score 3):

**Пивовары, особенно в крупных городах, работают официально и вчерную ничего не продают.**

Скорее всего, это вариант наречия ***втёмную***  тем же значением, и такое наречие должно писаться  слитно.

**Примеры:**

Гесер и Ольга разыграли меня **втемную** в каких-то своих играх. [Сергей Лукьяненко. Новогодний Дозор (2014)]

Не толкать же колёса **втёмную**. Использовали их **втемную,** как говорилось на жаргоне.

Answer (score 2):

Интересная информация есть на [**Грамоте**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5&start=15):
**Вопрос** № 282716
Здравствуйте.
Есть ли в русском языке наречие "вбелую", по аналогии с "внаглую"? Можно ли писать: "Работодатель платит зарплату вбелую"? То же самое интересует и насчёт "вчёрную".
Спасибо.
**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка
Наречия ***вбелую, вчерную*** не фиксируются словарями литературного русского языка. Их употребление нежелательно.

Однако, есть такая книга [**Ошибка "2012". Мизер вчерную**](https://www.labirint.ru/books/290209/) (М. Семенова, Ф. Разумовский. 2011). Думаю, что слово *вчерную* можно отнести к неологизмам (и писать его, конечно, следует слитно).

Answer (score 0):

Есть наречие *по-чёрному*:

> 2.разг. тайно, незаконно ◆ ― Не отдала, ― помог я. ― Вы по-чёрному, что ли, договаривались? ― Ну да, ― сказала она более или менее нормально. А. Г. Волос, «Недвижимость», 2000 г. // «Новый мир» (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка, см. Список литературы)

"Вчёрную" в словарях найти мне не удалось, но в Нацкорпусе можно найти.

> ― А разве классическая экономика учитывает такую вещь, как работа «вчерную». [Ирина Фадеева. «Антикризис» по-ульяновски: возьмите фабрику и сделайте так, чтобы она работала (2003) // «Мебельный бизнес», 2003.05.15]
>
> Либо площади малы, либо просят платить «вчерную». [Дмитрий Каралис. Автопортрет (1999)]